# Is there a speedfolder like entity in installshield?

Tags: installshield, installanywhere

I seem to have received the privilege of picking up some install shield projects.  I've used install anywhere in the past and I was wondering if there was an equivalent of speedfolder in installshield.  A speedfolder is a way of blindly copying an entire folder into the project without explicitly selecting each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

[Dynamic File Linking](http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/HelpLibDevStudio9/IHelpDynamicFileLinking.htm) or using the [Files and Folders](http://helpnet.acresso.com/robo/projects/installshield12helplib/IHelpISXFiles.htm) view.

With Dynamic File linking you can point your project to a directory or directories and IS will refresh the list of files at build time and add them to your install.

The files and folder view can be used to drag and drop a whole load of files and folders in to your project in one go.

If you choose to use Dynamic File Linking be sure to read up on the implications first.  Check out the Installshield help file